# Proof of # of FLOPs in Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to prove the number of FLOPs that a matrix multiplication would use. The matrices are of the form $(n \times p)$ and $(p \times m)$. I know that the number of FLOPs is equal to

> $$nm(2p-1).$$

However, I cannot find a way to prove it. I am not even sure if this is something you can prove or not, but I figured I would try asking.

Comment: This is the case for a "naive" matrix multiplication algorithm, constructing the output element by element.  There are so-called "fast" matrix multiplication algorithms whose *flop* count will differ from that shown above.

Comment: @hardmath That depends on the definition of FLOP. Fast matrix multiplications are fast because they do not count additions but multiplications only. Here a "FLOP" includes additions too and then fast algorithms do not look that "sexy" anymore :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $n\times m$ elements in the output matrix. Each of them is obtained by $p$ multiplications (1 element from the first matrix and 1 from the second), then summing up. Since you have $p$ products, you add $p-1$ of them to the first one. So the number of operations for one element in the output matrix is $p$ multiplications and $p-1$ additions, meaning $2p-1$ FLOPS. Then for all elements, you get $n\times m\times (2p-1)$ FLOPS.

Comment: I understand that is how it equals that, but I am wondering if there is a way to prove it. Such as using induction or something along the lines of that.

Comment: @JStefanik A proof is just a precise explanation of why a mathematical fact is true. Andrei has given a proof.

Comment: Intel MKL uses _p_ fused multiply-add instructions to compute dot products.